# how to check row contains all given values in postgres

Tags: sql

Have 2 table `table a` and `table b`,

`table A` - `id` (primary key)
`table B` - `aId`(foreign key), `userId`, `date`

ex :

table A

```
|id|
|--|
|1|
|2|
|3|
```

table B

```
|aId (foreign key)|userId|
|--|--|
|1|1|
|1|2|
|2|1|
|3|3|
```

need to fetch `id` which contains both 1 and 2 `userId`

tried by below SQL with in but returns either but not both

```sql
SELECT ta.id 
FROM tableA ta 
JOIN tableB tb ON ta.id = tb.taId 
WHERE tb.userId in (1,2);
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way using intersect.

```
select taid from tableb where userid = 1
intersect
select taid from tableb where userid = 2
```

another using group by

```
select
taid
from
tableb
where
userid in (1, 2)
group by
taid
having
count(distinct userid) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with data
  as (select 1 as userid
      union all
      select 2 as userid
      )
   select m.tableaid
         ,count(distinct n.userid)
     from data m
left join tableB n
       on m.userid=n.userid
 group by m.tableaid
having count(distinct n.userid)=2
```